# Django-celery deprecation error?

Tags: django, celery

I just started up django-celery and got this warning:

```
DeprecationWarning: 
The `celery.decorators` module and the magic keyword arguments
are pending deprecation and will be deprecated in 2.4, then removed
in 3.0.

`task.request` should be used instead of magic keyword arguments,
and `celery.task.task` used instead of `celery.decorators.task`.

See the 2.2 Changelog for more information.
```

Here's my test task:

```
from celery.decorators import task
@task()
def myProcessingFunction():
  print "Zing!"
  return 1
```

I'm calling it from a view with:

```
myProcessingFunction.delay()
```

I can't find any documentation for this error. What's going on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's telling you that the decorator you are using (task()) is going to be taken out of subsequent versions of celery so you should look to remove it from your code:

> celery.task.task`should be used instead of`celery.decorators.task`

so

```
from celery.task import task # instead of celery.decorators
@task()
def myProcessingFunction():
    print "Zing!"
    return 1
```

Comment: Came across the same issue. Perhaps some of the [celery documentation](http://django-celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-django.html) needs updating.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/internals/deprecation.html#old-task-api it sounds like you should also now change

```
from celery.task import task
```

to

```
from celery import task
```